# Declare field of abstract type? Prefer pointer or reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, member

I have an abstract class that looks something like

```
class Protocol
{
public:
    // format the string to json or xml depending on impl
    virtual std::string& format(Message& msg) = 0;
    // parse the message from json or xml depending on impl
    virtual Message& parse(std::string& str) = 0;
}
```

for formatting parsing a `structure Message` from/to a `std::string`

```
struct Message
{
    unsigned long id;
    unsigned char command;
    unsigned int value;

    /* some more fields */
}
```

Now I have another class `` that relies on that class by having a member of that type. Of course this member is expected to be of a subtype of `Calculator`

```
// client.h
class Client
{
public:
    Client(Protocol& protocol);

    /* some methods, e.g. */
    void request(unsigned int amout);

private:
    /* this is what the question below refers to */
    Protocol* pProtocol;   // will compile
    Protocol  cProtocol;   // won't compile (see below)
    Protocol& rProtocol;   // what does this mean?
}

// client.cpp

Client::Client(Protocol& protocol) :  
    // depending on the member
    pProtocol(&protocol) // or
    cProtocol(protocol)  // or
    rProtocol(protocol)
{
}

void Client::request(unsigned int amount)
{
    Message msg;
    msg.id = 1234;
    msg.command = 100;
    msg.value = amount;

    std::string str = 
    // depending on the member
                      pProtocol->format(msg);  // or
                      cProtocol.format(msg);   // or
                      rProtocol.format(msg);

    // some more code to send the string to the server
}
```

So here are my questions:

- I know I should prefer members of class type like `cProtocol` since pointers like `pProtocol` may be `NULL`
- unfortunately this won't compile with the message

  ```
  cannot declare field 'Client::cProtocol' to be of abstract type 'Protocol'
  ```

  which I understand, since the abstract class `Protocol` cannot be instantiated.
- So **what should I prefer? A reference member or a pointer member?**
- **What are the differences between the 3 options?** Especially between `cProtocol`and `rProtocol` (except `.`vs. `->` and the fact that the pointer may be `NULL`)
- **What if I don't initialize `rProtocol` in the constructor?** Will this compile? What would it contain? Since it cannot be instantiated with a default value!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I should prefer members of class type like `cProtocol` since pointers like `pProtocol` may be `NULL`

Generally, you prefer objects to pointers, because the language helps you manage resources by calling destructors on them. However, you can achieve the same effect with smart pointers, such as `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

> unfortunately this won't compile with the message "cannot declare field `Client::cProtocol` to be of abstract type `Protocol`" which I understand, since the abstract class Protocol cannot be instantiated.

This is not the right reason: it is done because of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), because slicing your objects down to an abstract type is not allowed.

> So what should I prefer? A reference member or a pointer member?

In order to use a reference, three conditions are necessary:

- The referenced object must be available in the constructor
- The presence of the referenced object is mandatory (because you cannot set a reference to `NULL`), and
- You do not need to re-point the referenced object to some other object, or "clear out" the reference at some later time.

If these three conditions are met, you can use a reference. This tells the readers of your code that your class instance has strong bounds to the referenced instance, because of the three conditions above.

> What are the differences between the 3 options? Especially between `cProtocoland` `rProtocol` (except `.` vs. `->` and the fact that the pointer may be `NULL`)

`cProtocoland` makes a copy (if it weren't abstract, it would) and slices off all the derived functionality. `rProtocol` uses some other object, and keeps it polymorphic. `pProtocol` gives you more flexibility on when to assign or re-assign it, and on assigning `NULL`s. In exchange for that you need to `NULL`-check the pointer, and optionally manage resources associated with it in copy constructors, assignment operators, and so on.

> What if I don't initialize `rProtocol` in the constructor? Will this compile? What would it contain? Since it cannot be instantiated with a default value!?

If you cannot initialize a reference in the constructor, you cannot use a reference for that member at all: a pointer becomes your only choice.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I come from Java and object-slicing was totally new for me!